# Metamask-Rinkeby Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code in Rinkeby?

Tags: metamask, rinkeby, error, exceptions

Can anyone explain why I'm get error every time for 'buyFor' function from my contracts?

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.11;
import "./ownable.sol";

contract GLOERC20Coin is Ownable{
    string public name;
    string public symbol;
    uint8 public decimals;
    uint256 public totalSupply;
    mapping (address => uint256) public balanceOf;
    mapping (address => mapping (address => uint256)) public allowance;

    event Transfer(address from, address to, uint256 value);
    event Approval(address from, address to, uint256 value);
    event Mint(address indexed to, uint256 amount);
    event Burn(address indexed burner, uint256 amount);

    function GLOERC20Coin(){
        decimals = 8;
        totalSupply = 10000000 * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
        balanceOf[msg.sender] = totalSupply;
        name = "MyToken";
        symbol = "MTS";
    }

    function _transfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) internal {
        require(_to != 0x0);
        require(balanceOf[_from] >= _value);
        require(balanceOf[_to] + _value >= balanceOf[_to]);

        balanceOf[_to] += _value;
        balanceOf[_from] -= _value;

        Transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    function transfer(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        _transfer(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    function transferFrom(address _from, address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        require(_value <= allowance[_from][_to]);
        allowance[_from][_to] -= _value;
        _transfer(_from, _to, _value);
    }

    function approve(address _to, uint256 _value) public {
        allowance[msg.sender][_to] = _value;
        Approval(msg.sender, _to, _value);
    }

    function mint(address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
        _amount = _amount * (10 ** uint256(decimals));
        totalSupply += _amount;
        balanceOf[msg.sender] += _amount;
        Transfer(address(0), msg.sender, _amount);
        Mint(msg.sender, _amount);
    }

    function burn(uint _amount) public onlyOwner {
        require(_amount <= balanceOf[msg.sender]);
        address burner = msg.sender;
        balanceOf[burner] -= _amount;
        totalSupply -= _amount;
        Burn(burner, _amount);
        Transfer(burner, address(0), _amount);
    }

    function insuranceCaseTransfer(address _from, address _to, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner {
        _transfer(_from, _to, _amount);
    }
}

///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

interface MyFirstERC20ICO {
    function transfer(address _receiver, uint256 _amount);
}

contract MyFirstSafeICO is Ownable{
    address owner;
    uint public buyPrice;
    MyFirstERC20ICO public token;

    function MyFirstSafeICO(MyFirstERC20ICO _token){
        token = _token;
        buyPrice = 10000;
        owner = msg.sender;
    }

    function () payable {
        _buy(msg.sender, msg.value);
    }

    function buy() payable returns (uint){
        uint tokens = _buy(msg.sender, msg.value);
        return tokens;
    }

    function buyFor(address _addressee, uint256 _amount) public onlyOwner returns (uint) {
        uint tokens = _buy(_addressee, _amount * buyPrice);
        return tokens;
    }

    function _buy(address _sender, uint256 _amount) internal returns (uint){
        uint tokens = _amount / buyPrice;
        token.transfer(_sender, tokens);
        return tokens;
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm guessing it's because of the `function _buy` you're dividing the amount by the buy price to retrieve the number of tokens the user shall receive. Since you're dividing by 10000 the amount would have to equal at least that same number for it to be stored inside of a uint. You can only store whole numbers inside uint, solidity doesn`t support floats or doubles. Afterward, you're trying to transfer 0 tokens since your previous math failed.

Comment: I tryed to buy up to totalSupply, but got the same error.